# Inkscape failed to load an exported file (Windows EMF) from ArcMap

Tags: inkscape, error

I created a street annotation feature class in ArcMap, then exported it to an EMF.

When I add a layer in Inkscape and try to import the EMF, I get the message: "Failed to load the requested file \gisfile\GISstaff\Jared\Projects\Attractions Layer\Highway Labels.emf".

I've already created a bunch of Inkscape layers using imported EMFs. As far as I know, I have exported and imported in the same way. This is the first time it failed.

Any ideas what may be the problem?

Comment: Update: I got the EMF to import into the Inkscape layer. What I did in ArcMap:
Export Map Menu--> Save as type: EMF--> Format tab-->check box: Convert Marker Symbol to Polygons

Comment: If you see this as a solution, write it as an answer. This makes it useful for someone else who possibly has the same problem. Now the solution is nonexistent in searches. It's not bizarre behaviour to write an useful answer by oneself until the history records show that the person do it continuously.